# Initializing variadic CRTP with static_cast<Base>(*this)... : is it legal ?

Tags: c++, c++17, crtp, static-cast

I have the following example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
struct foo { int x{}; };
struct bar { double y{}; };

template<typename... Base>
struct Foo : Base...
{
    constexpr auto init_int(int x) const
    { return Foo<foo, Base...>{foo{x}, static_cast<Base>(*this)...}; }
    constexpr auto init_double(double x) const
    { return Foo<bar, Base...>{bar{x}, static_cast<Base>(*this)...}; }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr auto f = Foo<>{}.init_double(.5).init_int(1234);
    static_assert(f.x == 1234);
    static_assert(f.y == 0.5);
}
```

This seems to work, in both recent Clang and GCC (with -std=c++1z), but not in MSVC2017. So I am not sure that this is legal C++: it seems to synthesize a constructor that looks like:

```
Foo(Base1 b1, Base2 b2, Base3 b3, ...): 
  Base1{b1},
  Base1{b2},
  Base3{b3},
  ... { }
```

Can I safely do this and be assured it is well-defined ?

Comment: _"but not in MSVC2017"_ I'd be more concerned if it's the other way round.

Comment: Generally speaking, if Clang and GCC accept a piece of code, while MSVC doesn't, it's usually not a sign the code is not valid C++.

Comment: I agree, but better safe than sorry :p

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier, have you tried C++ latest switch in MSVC? I believe they also had something like permissive-

Comment: The error you get is completely unrelated to `static_cast<Base>(*this)...`. `struct foo { int x; }; struct bar : foo {}; int main() { bar x{1}; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since C++17, aggregates can have public non virtual base classes of aggregate type. `foo` and `bar` are aggregates, so `Foo<foo,bar>` is an aggregate, and hence *aggregate-initialization* is used when brace-initialized.

So, the code is legal in C++17 and above ( it's not before ). Note that no 'aggregate constructor' is synthesized, it's just that brace-initialization has a special interpretation for aggregates.

BTW, I see no CRTP here (Foo does not inherit from a template specialization having a template argument depending on the super type)